# array of boost dynamic_bitset. If arr[0][0] bit is set, arr[1][0]test() is also set

Tags: c++11, boost

I have initialized array of dynamic bitset as follows

```
std::vector<boost::dynamic_bitset<>> v 
    = std::vector<boost::dynamic_bitset<>>(8, boost::dynamic_bitset<>(2));
```

I have set `v[0].set(0)` but `v[1].test(0)` return true.
If I set `v[0][0] = 1`, automatically other array 0th index bit is also considering as set.

I have set v[0].set(0) but v[1].test(0) return false.

Answer (score 0):

What you describe cannot happen with just the code given/described:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5539778d33775755)**

```
#include <boost/dynamic_bitset/dynamic_bitset.hpp>
#include <iostream>

void print(auto caption, auto const& v) {
    std::cout << caption << ":\t";
    for (auto& x : v)
        std::cout << " " << x;
    std::cout << "\n";
}

int main() {
    auto v = std::vector(8, boost::dynamic_bitset<>(2));

    print("before", v);

    v[0].set(0);

    print("after", v);
}
```

Printing

```
before:  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
after:   01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

If you still see the effect you describe, it means

- that you're doing something else
- surrounding code has [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) and anything can happen